# Smarty code in email message subject

Tags: civimail, smarty

I know nothing about smarty (it's on my to do list to start learning!) and I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like this in the message subject (or message body) of a bulk email:

If {contact.first_name} is blank
Then "Friend"
else {contact.first_name}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set CIVICRM_MAIL_SMARTY to 1 in civicrm.settings.php file to execute smarty logics. And then can use below code in your message template

```
{capture assign=contactName}{contact.first_name}{/capture}
{if $contactName}{$contactName}{else}{ts}Friend{/ts}{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I know we are already using smarty in other templates so hopefully I can just use this code as is!

Comment: Spoke too soon - the subject line has a character limit of 128 so I don't think this can be done

Comment: In recent versions of civi and with flexmailer you don't need the capture part anymore, you just have to put quotes around the token in the `if`, e.g. try `{if '{contact.first_name}'}{contact.first_name}{else}{ts}Friend{/ts}{/if}`

Comment: If you are on latest Civi you can remove the capture section, hopefully that should reduce the chars